# Why didn't Rashi mention lo sechanem includes gifts

Tags: gentiles, rashi, vaeschanan, masecheth-avodah-zarah

Devarim 7:2 says:

> וּנְתָנָ֞ם יְהוָ֧ה אֱלֹהֶ֛יךָ לְפָנֶ֖יךָ וְהִכִּיתָ֑ם הַחֲרֵ֤ם תַּחֲרִים֙ אֹתָ֔ם לֹא־תִכְרֹ֥ת לָהֶ֛ם בְּרִ֖ית וְלֹ֥א תְחָנֵּֽם׃
>
> and the LORD your God delivers them to you and you defeat them, you must doom them to destruction: grant them no terms and give them no quarter.

Rashi explains:

> ולא תחנם. לֹא תִתֵּן לָהֶם חֵן, אָסוּר לוֹ לְאָדָם לוֹמַר "כַּמָּה נָאֶה גוֹי זֶה!״ דָּבָר אַחֵר, לֹא תִּתֵּן לָהֶם חֲנִיָּה בָּאָרֶץ
>
> ולא תחנם means, THOU SHALT NOT ASCRIBE GRACE (חן) TO THEM: it is forbidden to a person to say “How beautiful is this heathen”. Another explanation: thou shalt not grant them a חניה, an encampment (a settlement) in the land.

He's quoting the gemarra in Avodah Zarrah 19b-20a, which lists these two prohibitions. However, the gemarra there lists a third prohibition:

> לא תחנם לא תתן להם חנייה בקרקע דבר אחר לא תחנם לא תתן להם חן דבר אחר לא תחנם לא תתן להם מתנת חנם
>
> "Nor give freely unto them" - do not grant them occupation of the land. Alternatively "nor give freely unto them" - do not grant them favor. Alternatively "nor give freely unto them" - do not give them free gifts.

Why didn't Rashi bring the prohibition of giving non Jews free gifts?

Comment: Which edition of Rashi did you check?

Comment: [Sefaria](http://Sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.7.2) has the version quoted by the OP.

Comment: @Double-AA I was using an Oz Vehadar Chumash. Sefaria had the same girsa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [R. Ovadya of Bertinoro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obadiah_ben_Abraham_Bartenura)'s Amar N'ke [commentary to Rashi here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22020&st=&pgnum=153&hilite=), it is apparent that Rashi **did** mention all three! He discusses why Rashi lists the three in the order that he does: favour, free gifts, and land. Clearly his version of Rashi had all three. The following is his initial quotation of Rashi which includes all three:

> לא תחנם לא תתן להם חן. ד"א לא תתן להם מתנת חנם. ד"א לא תתן להם חניה בקרקע

Alternatively, the [Sefer Hazikkaron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_L%C3%A9vy-Bacrat) (early 16th century) to Rashi there writes that Rashi did not quote that opinion since it is not unanimous, or necessarily universally applicable.:

> הרב ז"ל לא הביאה דלאו אליבא דכולי עלמא היא כדאמרינן התם בשלהי פרק קמא 
>   דעבודה זרה מתנת חנם תנאי היא. ואף קצת הפוסקים שכתבוה התירו בשכנו או מכירו ולכן השמיטה הרב

Comment: Nice addition with Sefer HaZikkaron; I didn't remember it was a machlokes.